# Which linq method is most suitable for judging whether there are elements in the set？

Tags: list, linq

```
var list = new List<object>();
```

1. `if (list.Any())`
2. `if (list.Count > 0)`
3. `if (list.FirstOrDefault() != null)`

Comment: This is considered subjective. They are all suitable, but `Any` conveys *intent* while the others have a slightly higher cognitive load. The last one in my experience is *highly unusual*.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three reasons why `Any` is better than the other 2 options:

- `Any` conveys the intent most cleanly
- If the collection is not an `ICollection<T>`, which has a built-in `Count` property, then `Count()` will traverse the whole collection. `Any()` will at worst stop iterating if, well, *any* element is found.
- `FirstOrDefault() == null` only works on collections of types where the default is actually `null`. It will not work on, say, a list of integers

There could also be edge cases which make the third option give wrong results. `FirstOrDefault() == null` could return `true` if there's some bizarre equality operator overload that returns true if an object is "equivalent" to `null`. That seems unlikely, but it could give a false positive for an "empty" collection.

If the collection is not an `ICollection`, then there should not be any meaningful performance difference between the three. The only other reason there would be a difference is if the collection implements `ICollection<T>` but has a strange override of `GetEnumerator` that does significantly more work even to just see if there is one item. That seems unlikely enough that I would only use `Count` in very specific circumstances with a significant, measurable performance benefit overall (not just compared to `Any`)

Comment: Perfectly clear answer. :-)